# Current employer is blacklisting me via HR at another company

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

What recourse do I have if I know that a current employer is blacklisting me via HR at another company?

I know by cross-checking people I know don't like me at current company and people who are related to HR or hiring at the other company.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: You don't know you are blacklisted and a company is free to decide to decline for no reason.

Comment: Multiple people at work dislike you enough to sabotage your career but in a way that keeps you working along side them?

Comment: Stay off social media. You led them to the intersecting circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any recourse it would be through the legal process. You might consult an employment lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

Apply elsewhere.

If you are in a locale where this happens, then there isn't anything you can do about it that doesn't have a strong chance of you becoming unemployed.

Answer (score 0):

If in the EU you could file a request under GDPR with your HR department, for any communications they hold about you.

Be aware:

1. They can withhold anything which would violate their confidentiality with another employee (e.g. your manager).
2. They are not obliged to handle this in confidence.